# How can I get more spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, spell-slots

I'm playing a protector aasimar paladin and I was wondering how I can get more spell slots.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Are you interested in increasing your spell slots by class or also in having magic items that can artifically allow you to cast more than you normally would?

Comment: If it is the latter, what level are you and how common are magic items in your world?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## By advancing your character's level

The only way to increase your total amount of spell slots is gain more levels. You can either continue gaining levels in [paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Paladin) or you can multiclass into another class. If you do multiclass, please see [this chart](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) which details how your spell slots would work.

Paladins are known as 1/2 casters, so their spell progression isn't as big as full casters. The trade off in multiclassing to get more slots from a larger caster class will be a delay in your paladin progression (which is a big deal, paladins get a lot of good stuff!)

It is important to note that the multiclass rules are entirely optional and up to the DM as to whether or not you are allowed to use them.

Answer (score 2):

While gaining levels or multiclassing give the character *more* slots, there are ways to *reuse* slots.

For instance, the [Pearl of Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/pearl-of-power):

> While this pearl is on your person, you can use an action to speak its command word and regain one expended spell slot.

Comment: While not literally granting additional slots, I think the Ring of Spell Storing fulfills the spirit of the question: https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing

Answer (score 0):

## Multiclass

Any full caster or a Warlock (depending on the usual number of short rests) will be a big boost.

### Sorcerer or Bard

1 level will not help, but any more will give you a lot of extra slots.

### Warlock

Depending on the number of short rests you usually get in a day, it might be better or worse than Sorcerer.

## Comparison to single-class Paladin

The most important (for DPR) Paladin feature is Extra Attack, the second is Divine Smite, the third Improved Divine Smite.
Adventuring days are short <sup>1</sup>, so IDS adds about 10d8 damage to your days (if you win all initiatives, less if not). If you go Paladin 8/Sorcerer 4 instead of Paladin 12, you get (3 * 4 + 2 * 3) = 18 d8 from the extra spell slots in case you spend them for Divine Smite. You are *way* ahead on raw damage, and in my opinion, the spells add much more versatility than what you lose on Paladin class features.

Paladin levels 5, 6, 8 are all good places to get out.

---

1) I have participated in nearly 150 sessions of 5e, and no encounter lasted longer than 5 rounds, on average a bit less than 3 rounds.
One adventuring day on average had no more than 5 rounds.
Data aggregated from 5 different DM's.

Comment: "One adventuring day on average had no more than 5 rounds." Do you mean 5 fights ? Or do your adventuring days have only 1 fight on average ?

Comment: @PierreCathé, a bit less than 1.5 on average