# What spells can a Bloodhunter Cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, blood-hunter

So I was wondering what spells a bloodhunter might be able to cast if any. I can't seem to find any help or details on what spells Bloodhunters can use, so if someone could kindly help me, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4):

The [Blood Hunter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter) class is fully detailed on the DnDBeyond site. It gains a number of features such as 'rites' (taking damage to enhance your weapons), curses etc, but does not cast spells by default.

Only the sub-class Order of the Profane Soul casts spells once you reach 3rd level. Their spellcasting feature works in a similar way as a warlock. A table is provided that indicates the spells they know and the spell slots that they get.

Comment: To clarify, a Profane Soul blood hunter's spellcasting isn't exactly the same as a warlock's. They seem to have the "one-third caster" spell slot progression that an Eldritch Knight fighter or Arcane Trickster rogue does - except with limited warlock-style slots that are refreshed on a short rest, and of course they use the warlock spell list.

Comment: @V2Blast: I just meant in the way it works, but I've tried to clarify

Answer (score 0):

### Standard Blood Hunter cannot cast spells

The [Blood Hunter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter) class by Matt Mercer is not a spellcasting class, it does not have the spellcasting feature and gains no spells and therefore does not have a list of spell it can cast. Instead they get a number of features that in previous edition would have been called "spell-like" or "supernatural" abilities (these terms do not exist in 5th Edition).

The class has two main spell-like are its [*Crimson Rite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#CrimsonRite-776) and [*Blood Maledict*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#BloodMaledict-778) features. [*Crimson Rite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#CrimsonRite-776) grants a number of different rites to add magical damage to your weapons, each rite dealing a different damage type. [*Blood Maledict*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#BloodMaledict-778) allows you to choose a number of features which are very similar to spells in the form of *Blood Curses*. Each *Blood Curse* is unique and works as per the rules given in the class description. They do not count as spells however.

### Order of the Profane Soul

There is one subclass of [Blood Hunter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter) called the [Order of the Profane Soul](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#OrderoftheProfaneSoul) that does get a form of spellcasting. This subclass grants the *Pact Magic* feature similar to the [warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock). Profane Soul Blood Hunters are to warlock what the Arcane Trickster Rogue and Eldritch Knight Fighter are to wizards. They are [half-casters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152448/48759) that use magic in the same manor as the main spellcasting class but to a lesser extent.

This subclass gains fewer spells as a lower rate than a true warlock. They start with 2 cantrips, and 2 spells known when they choose the subclass at third level. Scaling to 3 cantrips and 11 spells known at 20th level. Each of these spell are chosen from the [warlock spell list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=7&filter-search=&filter-sub-class=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-unlocked-content=), not including the expanded spell list granted by each of the warlock patrons.

The Order of the Profane Soul do still choose a patron however. These patrons instead grant unique powers and once per long rest casts of certain spells at 7th and 15th level.

So the answer to your question is:

**Blood Hunter's cannot cast spells, unless they take the Order of the Profane Soul subclass. Then they can cast spell from the warlock spell list to a limited degree.**